# pip install editable fails in windows if .git folder is present

Tags: python, windows, git, pip, anaconda

If I create a bare-bones package as:

```
eg/
  setup.py
  eg/
     __init__.py
     mod.py
```

with a setup.py whose content is

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='eg',
  version='1.0.0.dev0',
  description='Example',
  url='',
  author='',
  author_email='',
  license='',
  packages=find_packages(),
  install_requires=[]
)
```

and a do-nothing module mod.py:

```
class EG():
    pass
```

it installs perfectly if I move to the eg/ folder and execute (Anaconda 3 Prompt in Windows)

```
pip install -e .
```

But if there is a .git folder in the package, i.e. :

```
eg/
  .git
  setup.py
  eg/
     __init__.py
     mod.py
```

I get the following error

```
 error: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
 File Finder Failed for .git = setuptools_scm.git:list_files_in_archive
```

Since I'm developing the package and making frequent commits, removing the .git folder is not an option. Do you know how to get pip install to work when there is a .git folder present?

PS: I haven't had such a problem in Ubuntu. This happens to me only in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [setuptools_scm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools_scm) which is not a standard package, that's why you don't have the problem in Ubuntu.

If you don't use `setuptools_scm` in your `setup.py` try to uninstall it:

```
pip uninstall setuptools_scm
```